# Meaning of precision 1, scale 0 in error message?

Tags: postgresql, errors, number-formatting

What datatype does this error message refer to?

> ```
> ERROR:  numeric field overflow
> DETAIL:  A field with precision 1, scale 0 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1.
> ```

I'm getting the error listed above, it's coming from an insert trigger. Since none of my datatype are explicitly defined as `NUMERIC(1,0)` and since the maximum value is 10 to the power of 1 (i.e. 10) I'm guessing that this error is actually referring to a `BOOLEAN` field. However, I can't find confirmation of this.

UPDATE
Solved. My trigger is attempting to parse some strings into numbers. The error listed is returned when `to_number()` doesn't get a string in the expected format.

This returns 1.4 (correct) -

```
select to_number('1.4','9D9');
```

This returns the aforementioned error

```
select to_number('1d4','9D9');
```

Still not quite sure why it's complaining about `NUMERIC(1,0)` but at least I know *why* there's an error.

Comment: The error clearly states it's a `numeric` column. If the column was defined as `boolean` the error message would be different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Do I need to be looking for a field (or variable) explicitly defined as NUMERIC(1,0) in one of database objects? Or could it be some internal POSTGRES thingy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `to_number()` drops anything but data characters from the input string. Data characters are: digits, sign, decimal point, and comma. Noise characters are not insignificant though, as they still count against the length of the format pattern. So:

```
SELECT to_number('1d4','9D9');
```

is effectively the same as:

```
SELECT to_number('14','9D9');
```

Both fail because the pattern `'9D9'` only allows a single digit before the comma.

But this valid expression:

```
SELECT to_number('1X4','99D9');  -- added digit to pattern
```

is *not* the same as:

```
SELECT to_number('1XXX4','99D9');
```

To much noise truncates the input.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d40689b6582ab9571e620739f943ba7f)*

And, yes, [`D` is a format specifier for a decimal point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE) (independent of locale) in the pattern string (2nd function argument), but not in the input string (1st function argument). You found that yourself already.

---

To address the question in the title - Postgres has a [definition in the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> The *precision* of a `numeric` is the total count of significant
> digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both
> sides of the decimal point. The *scale* of a `numeric` is the count of
> decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal
> point. So the number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4.
> Integers can be considered to have a scale of zero.

---

That said, I see **two Postgres issues** here:

#### 1. Missing documentation

It's not documented [in the manual that `to_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) ignores non-data characters in the input. Nor that those still count against the total length of the pattern.

#### 2. Bug in error message

There seems to be an error in the *DETAIL* of the error message. The observed:

> ```
> DETAIL:  A field with precision 1, scale 0 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1.
> ```

Should really be:

> ```
> DETAIL:  A field with precision 2, scale 1 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1.
> ```

The effect is the same, so the behavior is coherent. But the information is misleading.